# How do you make a command block activate a title when a player dummy gets 5 points?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I tried saying

```
/testfor @a[scores={Score=5}]
```

but it said no targets found.

Answer (score 1):

I assume by "player dummy" you mean a fake player? Because otherwise if your scoreboard objective is called `Score` (`/scoreboard objectives add Score dummy`) then your code should work just fine in detecting players with a score of exactly 5. If you need 5 or above, you need to add two dots after the 5: `5..`.

Selectors like `@a` only work on actual entities, not on fake players. To test a fake player score, you need to use the [`execute if score` command](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands/execute#(if%7Cunless)_score):

```
execute if score .fake_player Score matches 5 run ...
```